# Aumentar el indice en el for each

Tags: java

En este caso estoy llenando un array con numeros aleatorios. Cuando utilizo un for normal el indice en cada iteracion aumenta de uno en uno, pero con el for each no logro realizar eso.

Adjunto el codigo

```
 Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    int nro;

    System.out.println("Digite  la cantidad de numeros con la que quiera llenar el arreglo de forma aleatoria");
    nro = lector.nextInt();

    int a[] = new int[nro];


   /* for(int i = 0; i < nro; i++){

     a[i] = (int) (Math.random()*100);   

        System.out.println("Indice " + i + " es igual " + a[i]);

    }*/



      for(int i : a){

       a[i] = (int) (Math.random()*100);   

      System.out.println("Indice "+ (1+i)  + " = " + a[i]);    

    }
```

Comment: qué es exactamente lo que hace t esa parte del for? o lo que intentas que haga? qué error te marca?

Comment: La mejor forma de utilizar un for each es sobre una lista o array previamente cargado o que tenga data.

Comment: gracias a ambos por su respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en ese for la variable i no tiene cada posición, sino que tiene el contenido de cada posición, o sea, si tu vector es [1,6,3], la variable i va a tener el valor 1, 6 y 3 en cada iteración.
En conclusión, para este ejercicio no sirve el `for(int i: a)`, debes utilizar el `for(int i = 0; i < nro; i++)`.
¡Suerte!

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta.saludos

Comment: Por nada! Si te sirvió por favor marca la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: no puedo hacerlo..ba..al tener menos de 15 en puntuacion mi voto se registra pero no se visibiliza en pantalla